# Android WebView: How setOffscreenPreRaster() works?

Tags: android, webview

I am learning `Android WebView`. During reading the `WebSettings` documentation I met this method: `setOffscreenPreRaster()`. 
Documentation says:
*Sets whether this WebView should raster tiles when it is offscreen but attached to a window.*

What does **raster tiles** mean? On what circumstances should I use this method in my `WebView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setOffscreenPreRaster(boolean)) says:

> Sets whether this WebView should raster tiles when it is offscreen but
>   attached to a window. Turning this on can avoid rendering artifacts
>   when animating an offscreen WebView on-screen. Offscreen WebViews in
>   this mode use more memory. The default value is false. Please follow
>   these guidelines to limit memory usage:
>
> - WebView size should be not be larger than the device screen size.
> - Limit use of this mode to a small number of WebViews. Use it for visible WebViews and WebViews about to be animated to visible.

More information found in [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=552398) thread:

> On android M (6.0), you can try [setOffscreenPreRaster](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setOffscreenPreRaster(boolean)). This essentially
>   redefines the visible viewport to the webview rect, and ignores
>   completely where webview is in relation to the screen. So the correct
>   way to use this would be to set it on a webview if it's about to
>   become visible, to minimize the downside that the webview would use
>   more memory while in background.

Comment: Does it mean that if I use this before eg. `loadDataWitheBaseURL` in `onAttachedToWindow` method the `WebView` will load faster?

Comment: From what I understood, you use this if you want to load your content into a webview and later show it to user to prevent any user inconvenience. This renders the webview tiles offscreen outside the view of the user. You can load the content once page rendering finishes. Therefore, it has to consume some memory to load its content in the background.

Comment: So, in easy words: it is gonna improve the performance or not?

Comment: As documentation states "Offscreen WebViews in this mode use more memory" so this won't improve performance but it will improve user interactivity and user interface.